# How to rename a target framework?

Tags: xcode, frameworks

What's the correct way to rename a framework in Xcode? You can just highlight it in the Targets view and press enter to rename it, but the folder containing the files doesn't actually get renamed. Is there an option somewhere that I'm missing?

Comment: A framework should likely be renamed within the project that originally created it.